# how to convert a jpeg in an array into a bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, image, forms

I have a functioning application in c#/.net that currently accepts raw image data in a bayer format from a set of embedded cameras and converts them to jpeg images.  To save transmission time, I have modified the embedded devices to encode the images as jpegs prior to transmission.  I'm an experienced embedded programmer but a total c#/.net noob.  I have managed to modify the application to save the arrays to file with a jpeg name using this snippet: ( the offset of 5 is to skip header data in the transmission frame)

```
FileStream stream = File.Create(fileName);
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
writer.Write(multiBuff.msgData, 5, multiBuff.dataSize - 5);
writer.Close();
```

The files open up fine, but now I want to treat the data as a bitmap without having to save & load from file.  I tried the following on the data array:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
byte[] headerData = reader.ReadBytes(5);
Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(stream);
```

But this throws a parameter not valid exception.  As a newbie, I'm a little overwhelmed with all the classes and methods for images and it seems like what I'm doing should be commonplace, but I can't find any examples in the usual places.  Any ideas?

Comment: This should work, assuming the byte stream is correct.  It isn't clear how *multiBuff.msgData* turned into *data*.  That's a smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Bitmap.FromStream()` :

```
Bitmap bmpImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
```

Actually using `new Bitmap(stream)` should have worked as well - this means that the data in the stream does not constitute a valid image - are you sure the jpg is valid? Can you save it to disk and open it i.e. in Paint to test?

Comment: This one worked, but you have to add an explicit cast to Bitmap.  Took me awhile to test because I had to track down a funny offset deep in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You use the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) class.

```
Image image;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: I think this one would work since Bitmap is just a special case of Image (at least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

FYI it didn't work because reader.ReadBytes(5) returns the 5 first bytes of stream not the bytes after position 5

Comment: that's not the error - it should read the first 5 bytes so the Bitmap can read the rest of the stream, see the problem definition in OPs question: *the offset of 5 is to skip header data in the transmission frame*

Comment: That's what I'm saying. It would have worked if he had written stream.Position = 5; byte[] headerData = reader.ReadBytes();  Or am I missing something ? The other solutions using FromStream are better though.